# What is the meaning behind "bloody jerry"

Tags: meaning

I've heard this term in a pirate movie or video game, not sure where. Since, I've been wondering what real meaning this sentence have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

["Jerry"](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/jerry) came from World War II, and is used to refer to the Germans in general.

> by shortening of German, originally from the First World War.
>
> Them Jerry planes are bombing Leicester!

It was also used in a derogatory way, so it evolved to be used as an insult on basically everything.

Comment: Why calling Germans "Jerry"? OOOh it refere to German-> Ger-man-> Ger-> Jerry.

Thanks you for clearing this up for me ^^

Comment: Shortening of "German". "German" pronounced "Jer-man", so naturally, shortening it becomes "Jerry".

Comment: "Used as an insult on basically everything?"  Really?  I'm pretty sure that's not true; I've only ever heard it in conjuction with German people or equipment, and almost always in a World War II context.

Comment: *Jerry-built* and *gerrymander* have different roots, but no doubt add to the insulting impression.

Comment: I thought ‘jerry-built’, which means ‘badly or hastily made’ was from this, but apparently it’s not, it’s much earlier.